# jwplayer rendering video smaller than box

Tags: javascript, video, video-capture, jwplayer

I'm trying to load this video so that it fills out the rest of the black space around it.

I'm not sure why it's shrinking the way that it is.

The video have been converted from wmv format to mp4 format using handbrake.

When I watch the original wmv format version of the same video it looks fine in VLC player, as in it fills in the area of the screen.

What might be the issue here?

Here is one of the examples where I'm having this issue:

http://access-success.co.uk/landers/launch.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under:

```
autostart: true,
```

Add:

```
stretching: 'none',
```

Comment: Much appreciated, fixed my issue completely. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, no problem! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me also but I'm using shortcodes on a page and in a widget area. So the code would be something like this:
[jwplayer player="1" mediaid="123" stretching="none"]

Hope this helps someone.